# VB.net Expression does not produce a value error

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, if-statement

I am brand new to vb.net and programming in general so sorry if this is a basic error but im trying to make a x's and o's game in vb.net and it keeps saying that my CheckForWin does not produce a value which makes zero sense to me and when i looked it up the only questions were about converting different code to vb.net and said nothing about the problem i was having
This my code:
Public Class Form1

```
Dim Board(9) As String
Dim Player1 As String = "X"
Dim Player2 As String = "O"

Public Property X As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub ResetBoard()
    Do
        If CheckForWin() = True Then
            Board(0) = 0
            Board(1) = 0
            Board(2) = 0
            Board(3) = 0
            Board(4) = 0
            Board(5) = 0
            Board(6) = 0
            Board(7) = 0
            Board(8) = 0

        End If
    Loop Until Board(0) = 0
    Board(1) = 0
    Board(2) = 0
    Board(3) = 0
    Board(4) = 0
    Board(5) = 0
    Board(6) = 0
    Board(7) = 0
    Board(8) = 0
End Sub

Private Sub CheckForWin()
    If "0""3""6" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "1""4""7" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "2""5""8" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "0""1""2" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "3""4""5" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "6""7""8" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "0""4""8" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "2""4""6" = X Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "0""3""6" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "1""4""7" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "2""5""8" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "0""1""2" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "3""4""5" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "6""7""8" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "0""4""8" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    ElseIf "2""4""6" = 0 Then
        ResetBoard()
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

The problem lies within this line of code:
If CheckForWin() = True Then

Comment: Your code expects CheckForWin to RETURN a boolean result, You'd need to change it to a function and return a boolean.

Comment: Why are you "checking for a win" in a method called "ResetBoard()"? I would expect that method to do nothing except "reset the board"...

Comment: What are you expecting to happen in these lines? `ElseIf "0""3""6" = 0 Then`  Why are you comparing a string containing `0"3"6` with the number 0 (zero)?

Comment: Thanks i fixed this error and now that part is working now thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

This line of code:

```vb
If CheckForWin() = True Then
    ...
End If
```

This sets up a conditional check to see if the result of the `CheckForWin` method is true. The issue is that the method is a Sub routine and not a Function.

A Function represents a block of code that returns a value whereas a Sub also represents a block of code but it does not return a value.

What's more is that it appears as if you have fallen into an infinite loop. `ResetBoard` calls `CheckForWin` which calls `ResetBoard` which calls... and so on.

The simplest thing to do would be to:

1. Convert the `CheckForWin` to a Function
2. Stop calling `ResetBoard` in the `CheckForWin` method
3. Return True when any of your conditional checks in the `ResetBoard` method is True

Here is an example:

```vb
Private Sub ResetBoard()
    ' check if there is a winner, if not then stop execution of the method early
    Dim isWin = CheckForWin()
    If (Not isWin) Then
        Return
    End If

    For index = 1 To 8
        Board(index) = 0
    Next
End Sub

Private Function CheckForWin() As Boolean
    Dim winningPatterns = {
        "0""3""6",
        "1""4""7",
        "2""5""8",
        ' etc...
    }
    Dim doAnyMatch = winningPatterns.Contains(X)
    Return doAnyMatch
End Function
```