# Syntax error in if statement in vb.net because of label

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, label, syntax-error

Im brand new to vb.net and to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question but im making a x's and o's game and im trying to display whos turn it is but my if statement keeps saying that i have a syntax error but it doesnt specify  what is wrong or how to fix it

Code:

```
Option Explicit On
Public Class Form1

    Dim Board(8) As String
    Dim Player1 As String = "X"
    Dim Player2 As String = "O"
    Dim XScore As String = ""
    Dim WhosTurn As String = Player1

    Public Property X As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ResetBoard()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResetBoard()
        WhosTurn = Player1
        For i = 0 To 8
            Board(i) = ""
        Next
        If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
            lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
        ElseIf WhosTurn <> Player1 Then
            End
        End If

        lblScorePlayer1X.Text = "Player 1 score"
        lblPlayer2O.Text = "Player 2 score"
        lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = 0
        lblP2ScoreNumber.Text = 0
        'If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
        'lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
        'ElseIf WhosTurn = Player2 Then
        'lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player two's turn"
        'End If
        Button1.Text = ""
        Button2.Text = ""
        Button3.Text = ""
        Button4.Text = ""
        Button5.Text = ""
        Button6.Text = ""
        Button7.Text = ""
        Button8.Text = ""
        Button9.Text = ""

    End Sub

    Private Function CheckForWin(ByRef PlayerToCheck As String) As Boolean



        'Player1 wins
        If (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(3) = PlayerToCheck And Board(6) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(1) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(7) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(2) = PlayerToCheck And Board(5) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(1) = PlayerToCheck And Board(2) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(3) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(5) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(6) = PlayerToCheck And Board(7) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(0) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(8) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        ElseIf (Board(2) = PlayerToCheck And Board(4) = PlayerToCheck And Board(6) = PlayerToCheck) Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False




    End Function





    Private Sub TakeTurn(ByVal Position As Integer)


        If (WhosTurn = Player1) Then
            Board(Position) = Player1
        Else
            Board(Position) = Player2

        End If
        'Check for win is here if you get confused 
        If (CheckForWin(WhosTurn) = True) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Player " & WhosTurn & " Won")
            ResetBoard()
            If WhosTurn = X Then
                lblP1ScoreNumber + 1 
            End If
            Return
            End If

            If (WhosTurn = Player1) Then

            WhosTurn = Player2
        Else

            WhosTurn = Player1
        End If

        If WhosTurn = Player2 Then
            lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player two's turn"
        ElseIf WhosTurn = Player1 Then
            lblPlayerTurn.Text = "It is player one's turn"
        End If
        'You've got that code wired to the label's on click event. Is that intended?
        'Shouldn 't it be at the bottom of the TakeTurn sub? Looks almost like you could replace 
        'that If statement and just set the label directly there instead of WhosTurn 
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Board(0) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button1.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(0)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        If Board(1) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button2.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        If Board(2) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button3.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(2)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        If Board(3) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button4.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(3)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        If Board(4) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button5.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(4)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
        If Board(5) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button6.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(5)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
        If Board(6) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button7.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(6)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
        If Board(7) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button8.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(7)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button9_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button9.Click
        If Board(8) <> "" Then
            Return
        End If
        Button9.Text = WhosTurn
        TakeTurn(8)
    End Sub

    Private Sub LabelTurn()

        If WhosTurn = Player1 Then
            lblPlayerTurn.Text = Player1
        Else
            lblPlayerTurn.Text = Player2
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

The problem is in this line of code:

```
(lblPlayerTurn) Text = Player1
```

same with the one for p2

Ive tried getting rid of the brackets but then it says that "Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses" and "Too many arguments to 'Friend WithEvents lblPlayerTurn as Label'" so thats why i tried closing the lblPlayerTurn in brackets

Comment: Should be `lblPlayerTurn.Text = ...`.  Not sure why you think it should be in parens or shouldn't have the dot?

Comment: What's wrong with just lblPlayerTurn.Text?

Comment: @Hursey i tried that the syntax error is gone now but the words arent displaying when i run it

Comment: You've got that code wired to the label's on click event.  Is that intended?  Shouldn't it be at the bottom of the TakeTurn sub?  Looks almost like you could replace that if statement and just set the label directly there instead of WhosTurn

Comment: You should RESOLVE your [Previous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75309103/2330053) that is obviously from the same project.

Comment: @Hursey Thanks i got it working now tbh i dont remember how i got it working should i edit the question to show the answer? (im new to asking questions on stackOverflow)

Comment: Add an answer and mark it as accepted if you can

Comment: There it should be up now but i have a similar problem but with this line of code:         
If WhosTurn = X Then
            lblP1ScoreNumber + 1                                                                                                        What im trying to do is add one every time either player one or two win any ideas?

Comment: In `LabelTurn()`, you can get rid of the whole `if...else` structure and just use: `lblPlayerTurn.Text = WhosTurn` That whole method/function literally needs just that one line...

Comment: lblP1ScoreNumber is a label control, with a text property that is a string.  You probably want to do something to extract the Text to a integer variable, then add 1 then set the text property again.  Might be better to ask another question rather than muddy up this one.  Also recommended reading https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement

Comment: `lblP1ScoreNumber + 1` This is not the correct way to do this.  `lblP1ScoreNumber` is a CONTROL (probably a Label?) that displays information in the form of a `String` via the `.Text` property. You should not be trying to do math (adding one) with a String. Instead, you should be declaring at FORM level a VARIABLE that holds an `Integer`, such as `Dim player1Score As Integer`.  Then you can add one to it with `player1Score = player1Score + 1` and update the label with the new value: `lblP1ScoreNumber.Text = player1Score`.

Comment: @Idle_Mind and Hursey thanks i have a error with doing lblP1ScoreNumber.Next = Player1Score but ill ask a new question as to not "muddle" this one up